# Type traits to check if class has member function

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits

Trying to create a way to identify if a given class has a given function that can be invoked, and returns some type.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong here? Is there a better way to determine if a given method is invoke'able given a class?

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#define GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(func, rettype)                                \
template<typename T, class Enable = void> struct has_##func;                   \
template<typename T, class U> struct has_##func : std::false_type {};          \
template<typename T>                                                           \
struct has_##func<T,                                                           \
                  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<                        \
                      typename std::result_of<decltype (&T::func)(T)>::type,   \
                      rettype>::value>::type> : std::true_type{};              \
template<class T> constexpr bool has_##func##_v = has_##func<T>::value;

GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(str, std::string)
GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(str2, std::string)
GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(funca, std::string)
GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(strK, std::string)
GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(fancy, std::string)
GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(really, std::string)

struct A1 {
    virtual std::string str() const { return ""; }
    std::string strK() const { return ""; }
    virtual std::string fancy()=0;
};

struct A2 : A1 {
    std::string str() const override { return ""; }
    std::string funca();
    std::string fancy() override { return ""; }
    std::string really(int a=0) const { return std::to_string(a); }

};

int main() {
    static_assert(has_str_v<A1>,
        "A1::str is virtual method with impl on base"); // MSVC: NO, clang: OK, GCC: NO
    static_assert(has_strK_v<A1>,
        "A1::strK is implemented inline "); // MSVC: NO, clang: OK, GCC: NO
    static_assert(has_fancy_v<A1>,
        "A1::fancy is a pure virtual method on base"); // MSVC: NO, clang: OK, GCC: NO
    static_assert(!has_really_v<A1>,
        "A1::really doesn't exist in A1"); // MSVC: OK, clang: OK, GCC: OK

    static_assert(has_str_v<A2>,
        "A2::str is override method "); // MSVC: OK, clang: OK, GCC: OK
    static_assert(!has_str2_v<A2>,
        "A2::str2 does not exist in A2"); // MSVC: NO, clang: OK, GCC: OK
    static_assert(has_funca_v<A2>,
        "A2::funca is defined (no impl) in A2"); // MSVC: OK, clang: OK, GCC: OK
    static_assert(has_strK_v<A2>,
        "A2::strK is implemented method on base"); // MSVC: OK, clang: OK, GCC: OK
    static_assert(has_fancy_v<A2>,
        "A1::fancy is a override of pure virtual method of base"); // MSVC: OK, clang: OK, GCC: OK
    static_assert(has_really_v<A2>,
        "A2::really has default param (can be invoked without params)"); // MSVC: OK, clang: NO, GCC: NO
    return 0;
}
```

Some surprises on this implementation.

EDIT:
Upon trying to implement @Jarod42 and @Vittorio Romeo awesome suggestions:

```
#define GENERATE_HAS_MEMBER_FUNC(func, rettype)                                \
template<class T> using _has_##func_chk =                                      \
      decltype(std::declval<T &>().func());                                    \
template<class T> constexpr bool has_##func##_v =                             \
      is_detected_exact_v<rettype, _has_##func_chk, T>;
```

now two test cases still fail on VS2015 (doesn't make any sense):
    static_assert(!has_really_v, "A1::really doesn't exist in A1"); 
    static_assert(!has_str2_v, "A2::str2 does not exist in A2");

there is probably something silly something that I'm missing... any clues?

Comment: Have you look at `std::is_detected` (C++17 but implementable in C++11) ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is there a better way to determine if a given method is invoke'able given a class?

Yes, you can use the [**detection idiom**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), which can be implemented in C++11 *(the linked page contains a valid implementation)*.

Here's an example: does `Cat` have a `float Cat::purr(int)` method?

```
struct Cat { float purr(int){} };

template<class T>
using has_purr = 
    decltype(std::declval<T&>().purr(std::declval<int>()));
    
static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected_exact_v<float, has_purr, Cat>);
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KzMaGZID9Ki4pGK2)

---

The required *detection idiom* C++17 dependencies are trivial to implement in C++11:

```
template< class... >
using void_t = void;

struct nonesuch {
    nonesuch() = delete;
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};
```

Here's a [**fully C++11-compliant minimal example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JsX5oYhCPGCa5Tlb).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to implement in MSVC and run the same tests. But making some small changes to quick test the scenarios in your wandbox code, looks like this is the best approach indeed,

Comment: Much more consistent results across compilers, but a couple tests are failing... how silly is my bug? (can't see it) :P

Comment: @nCoder: can you post a minimal example on wandbox with the errors?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/qJ09hr    (Just to clarify: only MSVC2015 is complaining - I guess I need to find something that works on VC)

Comment: The C++17 dependencies you listed (`void_t`, `nonesuch`) are not what your detection idiom uses (`std::experimental::is_detected_exact_v`).

Comment: I can't connect to the site with the code samples (https://melpon.org/). Perhaps the site is down?

Comment: @NullPointerException: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JsX5oYhCPGCa5Tlb

Answer (score 4):

I see it is an old question, but the answer is depending on experimental feature.
In [codereview.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194798/implementation-of-has-member-function) there is answer which does not use experimental feature. Just in case here is answer copied from the [source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194798/implementation-of-has-member-function):

```
template <typename Container, typename Element>
using pushback_t = decltype(std::declval<Container>().push_back(std::declval<Element>()));

template <typename Container, typename Element, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct has_pushback : std::false_type{};

template <typename Container, typename Element>
struct has_pushback<Container, Element, std::void_t<pushback_t<Container, Element>>>:
                        std::true_type{};

template <typename Container, typename Element>
inline constexpr bool has_pushback_v = has_pushback<Container, Element>::value;
```