# How to write a size() function that works on any type of collection objects?

Tags: c++, templates, mfc, c++17

I require a simple way to obtain the count / length / size of an object of class `T` where `T` is some sort of collection type, such as a `std::map`, `std::list`, `std::vector`, `CStringArray`, `CString`, `std::string`, …

For most of the standard types, `T::size()` is the correct answer, for most of the MFC classes `T::GetSize()` is correct and for `CString`, it is `T::GetLength()`.

I want to have a like:

```
template <typename T> auto size(const T & t)
```

...which evaluates to the correct member function call.

It seems like there should be a simple way to invoke a traits template on `T` which has a `size(const T & t)` member, which itself uses SFINAE to exist or not exist, and if it exists, then it is by definition calling an appropriate `t.size_function()` to return the count of elements in that instance of a `T`.

I could write an elaborate `has_member` type-trait template - there are a few examples on stackoverflow - all of them quite convoluted for what seems to me "there must be a simpler approach". With C++ 17, it seems like this issue should be easily and elegantly solved?

These discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936763/type-traits-to-check-if-class-has-member-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) seems to use an inelegant solution with some of the answers using preprocessor macros to get the job done.  Is that still necessary?

But... surely, there must be a way to use the fact that calling the correct member function on a `T` is compilable, and calling the wrong one fails to compile - can't that be used **directly** to create the correct type traits wrapper for a given type `T`?

---

I would like something along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
auto size(const T & collection)
{
    return collection_traits<T>::count(collection);
}
```

Where the exact specialization of `collection_traits<T>` is selected because it is the only one that fits for `T` (i.e. it calls the correct instance method).

Comment: In C++17 you can use constexpr-if to considerably reduce the complexity of type traits.

Comment: @Holt - thanks for the edits.  GJ

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [**expression SFINAE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae) and multiple overloads.

The idea is as follows: check if `x.size()` is a valid expression for your type - if it is, invoke and return it. Repeat for `.getSize` and `.getLength`.

Given:

```
struct A { int size() const { return 42; } };
struct B { int getSize() const { return 42; } };
struct C { int GetLength() const { return 42; } };
```

You can provide:

```
template <typename T>
auto size(const T& x) -> decltype(x.size()) { return x.size(); }

template <typename T>
auto size(const T& x) -> decltype(x.getSize()) { return x.getSize(); }

template <typename T>
auto size(const T& x) -> decltype(x.GetLength()) { return x.GetLength(); }
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    size(A{});
    size(B{});
    size(C{});
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3wbJT37HEd0aAmOT)

This solution is easy to extend and seamlessly works with containers that are templatized.

---

> What if a type exposes two getters?

The solution above would result in ambiguity, but it's easy to fix by introducing a ranking/ordering that solves that.

Firstly, we can create a `rank` class that allows us to arbitrarily prioritize overloads:

```
template <int N> struct rank : rank<N - 1> { };
template <>      struct rank<0> { };
```

`rank<N>` is implicitly convertible to `rank<N - 1>`. An exact match is better than a chain of conversions during overload resolution.

Then we can create a hierarchy of `size_impl` overloads:

```
template <typename T>
auto size_impl(const T& x, rank<2>) 
    -> decltype(x.size()) { return x.size(); }

template <typename T>
auto size_impl(const T& x, rank<1>) 
    -> decltype(x.getSize()) { return x.getSize(); }

template <typename T>
auto size_impl(const T& x, rank<0>) 
    -> decltype(x.GetLength()) { return x.GetLength(); }
```

Finally we provide an interface function that begins the dispatch to the right `size_impl` overload:

```
template <typename T>
auto size(const T& x) -> decltype(size_impl(x, rank<2>{})) 
{ 
    return size_impl(x, rank<2>{}); 
}
```

Using a type like `D` below

```
struct D
{
    int size() const { return 42; }
    int getSize() const { return 42; }
    int GetLength() const { return 42; }
};
```

will now choose the `rank<2>` overload of `size_impl`:

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2ka5hkCGuc73f0A8)

Comment: Note that in C++17, `std::size` is part of the standard, so the first overload could mess up with it, see e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/yCuajm

Comment: so I can avoid the 1st version, or use a different non-colliding name, such as count().  Similarly, I could place the above in a namespace, and then when ambiguity occurred, use explicit name?  Better ideas?

Comment: Note that if a (hypothetical) container type defines both `size()`, and `GetLength()` (for whatever reason), this approach will choke with a compiler error. While substitution failure is not an error, too much substitution success can be. (Though this approach can be rescued by providing a specialization specifically for that particular noisome type.)

Comment: @Mordachai If possible, put the function in the same namespace as the class you want it to work for. This will generate less interference and the function will still be found by ADL when used without namespace prefix. E. g. `namespace ATL { template <typename T>
auto size(const T& x) -> decltype(x.GetLength()) { return x.GetLength(); } };` for `CString`.

Comment: @R.M. considering that `std::string` has both `size()` and `length()`, it's not even *that* hypothetical :p

Comment: @Morwenn in my case, `size` and `GetLength` and `GetSize` are never (knock on wood) all defined for the same types.  I'm not sure if they ever would be - but if they are, I like @R.M.'s suggestion to just overload on that specific type.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest solution, IMO, is function overloading.

```
// Default implementation for std containers.
template <typename Container>
std::size_t size(Container const& c) { return c.size(); }

// Overloads for others.
std::size_t size(CStringArray const& c) { return c.GetSize(); }
std::size_t size(CString const& c) { return c.GetLength(); }
// ... etc.
```

Comment: This absolutely works, and has no ambiguity.  I just prefer elegance + leveraging the compiler to do the right  thing where possible, rather than having to spell it all out for it :)

Comment: @Mordachai, I agree with you that the other solution is definitely more elegant

Answer (score 2):

You need [expression SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae), and you must play nice with other types which might decide to conform to both interfaces, so study [`std::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).
The goal is to **augment `std::size()`** to work on all types which follow at least one of the conventions, as long as they don't mess up trying to follow any of them.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

namespace internal {
    // Avoid conflict with std::size()
    template <class C>
    auto size_impl(const C& c, int) -> decltype((void)c.size());

    // Avoid conflict with std::size()
    template <class T, std::size_t N>
    void size_impl(const T (&array)[N], int);

    template <class C>
    constexpr auto size_impl(const C& c, long)
    noexcept(noexcept(c.GetLength()))
    -> decltype(c.GetLength())
    { return c.GetLength(); }

    template <class C>
    constexpr auto size_impl(const C& c, long long)
    noexcept(noexcept(c.getSize()))
    -> decltype(c.getSize())
    { return c.getSize(); }
};

template <class T>
using enable_if_not_void_t = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<T>(), T>;

using std::size;
template <class C>
constexpr auto size(const C& c)
noexcept(noexcept(internal::size_impl(c, 0)))
-> enable_if_not_void_t<decltype(internal::size_impl(c, 0))>
{ return internal::size_impl(c, 0); }
```

You can get arbitrary levels of precedence for extending things using templates and inheritance:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct priority : priority<N - 1> {};
template <>
struct priority<0> {};
```

Something like the proposed [Abbreviated Lambdas for Fun and Profit](https://wg21.link/p0573) would greatly simplify things.

Comment: I had to make some minor fixes to build this code (also see [live compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tLCYWF4LZIValffC)). Also I believe that the array overload of `size_impl()` is not necessary, because one always has to use namespace prefix for `size()` when using it with arrays, but I might be wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the fix. And I want to allow importing both into the base scope for uniform use.